# R ggplot quarter circle line through scatterplot

Tags: r, probability

Okay basically I need to generate a runif between 0:1 with a and a y cordinate.

create two variables

= points_within_circle
= points_outside_circle

and for every combined point if its above 1 it should incrase points_outside and if its below inside, it says the criteria I'm following is p x2 + y2 ≤ 1

I'm kinda lost and don't know how to do this,

this is how far I have gotten and ive been trying to find information but I just can't find it.

```
x <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)

data.circle <- data.frame(x,y)

points_within_circle <- 0

points_outside_circle <- 0


data.circle %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point(size =3)
```

[image: here is a visual help, its in swedish]

Comment: Add more columns to your data. Here's a small step forward: `data.circle$radius_sq <- data.circle$x^2 + data.circle$y^2`

Comment: okay I think I gotten that part now, but the next task is to add these lines thatintercept, how would I go about doingthat? I experimented with: 



`code`

arcs <- data.frame(
  start = 0.5,
  end = 3,
  r = 0.5)


ggplot() +                              
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_arc(data=arcs,aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = r, start = start, end = end),size = 8)`code`


`code`

Comment: figured it out, added an angle variable in the vector 

`arcs3 <- data.frame(
  start = 0,
  end = 1,
  r = 0.4,
  angle = c(1, pi/2))`


`ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x, y), size = 4) +
  geom_arc(data=arcs, aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0.0, r = r, start = start, end = angle),size = 3, `